# keep match in pandas Dataframe column and remove the rest

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list called *names*

```
names = ['kramer hickok', 'carlos ortiz ', 'talor gooch', 'mikumu horikawa', 'yoshinori fujimoto']
```

In addition, I have a `pandas.DataFrame` called *page*. The dataframe looks as follows:

```
     name
--   ---------------------------
0    kramer hickok united states   
1    carlos ortiz mexico  
2    talor gooch united states    
3    mikumu horikawa japan
4    yoshinori fujimoto japan
```

I want to replace all the countries from the column. How can I do this as fast as possible?

The desired output:

```
     name
--   ---------------------------
0    kramer hickok  
1    carlos ortiz 
2    talor gooch 
3    mikumu horikawa 
4    yoshinori fujimoto
```

I tried the following with no result:

```
for name in names:
   page['name'] = page['name'].str.extract(name)
```

Thank you

Comment: Is every name two words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.str.extract`

```py
page['out'] = page['name'].str.extract(r'\b(' + '|'.join(names) + r')\b')
```

```
print(page)

                          name                 out
0  kramer hickok united states       kramer hickok
1          carlos ortiz mexico        carlos ortiz
2    talor gooch united states         talor gooch
3        mikumu horikawa japan     mikumu horikawa
4     yoshinori fujimoto japan  yoshinori fujimoto
5  mikumumikumu horikawa japan                 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just replacing the column at all?

```py
page['name'] = names
```

I think it would take less time and much easier to handle.

( ※ Note that there should be no duplicate in the names if using this code.)

Answer (score 0):

If every name is just two words, you don't even need your list:

```
df.name = df.name.str.extract('(\w+ \w+)')
print(df)
# Output:
                 name
0       kramer hickok
1        carlos ortiz
2         talor gooch
3     mikumu horikawa
4  yoshinori fujimoto
```

Comment: Thanks but not every name is two words